# API Platform custom operation with custom parameter

Tags: rest, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I just started using the dunglas api platform. Im using v2.0.0-rc1 and i added an custom operation to enabled/disable an user.

This is my custom action for the user

```
<?php

namespace Zoef\UserBundle\Action;

use Zoef\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class UserAction
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="enabled_user",
     *     path="/users/{id}/enabled",
     *     defaults={"_api_resource_class"=User::class, "_api_item_operation_name"="enabled"}
     * )
     * @Method("PUT")
     */
    public function __invoke(User $user)
    {
        if($user->isEnabled()) {
            $user->setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            $user->setEnabled(true);
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

When i go to my docs the custom operation is added and functional but to use this action i need to send 4 parameters: email, fullname, username, enabled. but i only want to send the enabled parameter and the id of the user is given in the route but i cant find in the doc how to change the parameters.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you getting a validation error? Can you post the result of the query PUT?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to make the same enable/disabled and I did it this way:

I created a custom controller in `AppBundle\Controller\AddressController`

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AddressController extends Controller
{
    public function enableAction($data)
    {
        $data->setActive(true);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

In my `routing.yml` I have:

```
address_enable:
    path:     '/addresses/{id}/enable'
    methods:  ['PUT']
    defaults:
            _controller: 'AppBundle:Address:enable'
            _api_resource_class: 'AppBundle\Entity\Address'
            _api_item_operation_name: 'enable'
```

In my entity, I have:

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "enable"={"route_name"="address_enable"},
 *     }
 * )
```

And after that I just send it as `URL/addresses/123/enable` no need to send more parameters, just the id.

Comment: This method is not recommended by ApiPlatform (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#alternative-method)